# Проблема с backgroundWorker

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Добрый день.

Возникла проблема с backgroundWorker, то есть он на 60% работает и на 40% не работает, причем все происходит рандомно, к примеру, при 3 попытках запуска работает, а при следующих 4 отключается на первом цикле. В чем может быть проблема?

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork_1(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        bool BeginCycle = true;
        while (BeginCycle != false)
        {
            GetSensorData();
            GraphMemory();
            if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
            {
                BeginCycle = false;
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            else if (!backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
            {
                BeginCycle = true;
                if (VariableVideoController.AdapterCompatibility[Form1.BufIndex] != MainClass.GetSensor.Vendor)
                {
                    this.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox17.Text = "N/A"));
                }
                try
                {
                if ( VariableVideoController.AdapterCompatibility[Form1.BufIndex] == MainClass.GetSensor.Vendor)
                {
                        this.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox17.Text = MainClass.GetSensor.GetGPUCore.ToString() + " MHz"));
                }
                }
                    catch (Exception Error)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
            }
        }
    }

        private void FormVideocardInfo_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
    }
```

Comment: @SergD29: У вас много кода. Вы не могли бы сократить пример до минимума? Например, неужели все-все текстбоксы так уж важны для понимания вашей проблемы? Также получение данных наподобие `GetSensorData()` — если оно важно для описания вашей проблемы, то дайте код, если нет, уберите его из примера.

Comment: @SergD29: С этим кодом проблем не видно. Покажите, как именно вы его запускаете.

Comment: Спасибо разобрался, забыл освободить ресурсы chart1:
 
    if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
                    {
                        BeginCycle = false;
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        this.Invoke(new Action(() => chart1.Dispose()));
                        return;
                    }
но все равно не понятно, почему у него был такой процент работы.

Comment: @SergD29 "_но все равно не понятно, почему у него был такой процент работы_" проблемы многопоточности. Ваш КЭП.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
            {
                BeginCycle = false;
                e.Cancel = true;
                this.Invoke(new Action(() => chart1.Dispose()));
                return;
            }
```